# How to get a byte pointer to a value of any data type in Golang?

Tags: optimization, go, reflection

I've managed to get the following function working in Go. But I want to optimize/generalize the code such that this function would return me a pointer to the first byte of any value I pass into the function. Currently it will only work for []uint32, but I want to use it to get the starting memory address as a *byte for many other types (i.e. byte[], int[], string, etc).

Is there a more generic way to do this rather than catching every single type I need to address as case statements?

Go Playground Link for below code: https://play.golang.org/p/KtNTbERQGa

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func ToBytePointer(data interface{}) *byte {
    fmt.Println("Received type is", reflect.TypeOf(data))

    switch data.(type) {
    case []uint32:
        typedData := data.([]uint32)
        return (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&typedData[0]))
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

func main() {
    var data = []uint32{1, 2, 3}
    var dataBytePointer = (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))

    fmt.Println(dataBytePointer, ToBytePointer(data))
}
```

Comment: I don't think this question can really be answered without defining how the resulting `*byte` is used. Without a clear notion of that, who's to say what are valid types for the conversion? You can probably work around some of the repetitive boilerplate with [`reflect.Value.Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Pointer)

Comment: @nothingmuch Think of it like this. I want to be able to get the starting memory address to any structure I can create in Go. You can compare that to getting a pointer to any data type or structure in C.

My real usage is for calling the method DeviceIoControl(Handle, uint32, *byte, uint32, *byte, uint32, *uint32, *Overlapped). 

This method needs pre-initialized memory buffers passed to it as arguments, but as *byte. The buffers sometimes consist of string, uint32, []byte, etc. So my intention is to create a util function which gives me the byte pointer to any underlying memory block.

Comment: Use reflection (see e.g. reflect.SliceHeader)

Comment: @Neo, you're not taking the starting address of the slice structure, you're taking the address of the backing array, which is an arbitrary field in the structure. You can make various exceptions if you like, but the backing array for a `string` isn't technically addressable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, I believe I've found what I was looking for. It can be done, just needed to dig a little bit into the reflection package of Go. I'll answer my own question just so that somebody else might find this helpful.

The elegant one liner to get the starting memory address of any allocated block of memory as a byte pointer in Go would be:

```
(*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(reflect.ValueOf(anyAllocatedDataGoesHere).Pointer()))
```

If anybody needs to check how it will behave for any data type, i.e []uint32, []byte, string, int, struct, have a look at this sample PlayGround I prepared.

https://play.golang.org/p/G5fUOCfNCS

Comment: You're going to need to know the type at some point, so why hide the type in an interface and use reflect when you could just convert the pointer directly? (and what's the point of having the `string` become a pointer to the string struct, while a `[]byte` becomes a pointer to the backing array?)

Answer (score 0):

Golang does not have generics, so I guess you need to catch every single type.

Also, in your example, you got the first byte of the first element in the slice, not the first byte of the value passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your application is, you might consider Gob encoding or protobuf (as used in Brad Fitz's [groupcache](https://github.com/golang/groupcache/blob/master/sinks.go)). You'd be making a copy of your data, and I'm pretty sure there's still reflection going on under the hood, but at least you're getting well-optimized copying & byte encoding, which may be a plus since I suspect the next step in your application once you have these bytes is a copy of some sort.